# jQuery post to method in class

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am in a legacy asp.net application and I need to call a method within a class via jQuery ajax post.

So far I have a class called `NewClass` with a single method;

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string jQuery_GetCategoryDescription(string CategoryName)
    {
        return "Slappy";
    }
```

I then have the following jQuery;

```
$.post('/NewClass/jQuery_GetCategoryDescription', { CategoryName: "trippy" }, function (newHTML) {
    alert(newHTML);
});
```

I've tried putting in the whole namespace in.

However I can't seem to call the method within the class.

**EDIT**

I am getting a 405 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string jQuery_GetCategoryDescription(string CategoryName)
    {
        return "Slappy";
    }
```

Is in side Index.aspx

You can call it by `/Index.aspx/jQuery_GetCategoryDescription`

Comment: the method is not within an aspx page at all.

Comment: Where is the method? In PageBase class or just a Class where it has no reference to page?

Comment: in a seperate class that has no reference to the page what so ever.

Comment: It needs to be in something that is accessible via http/s. So put it in a page (as a public static webmethod), or place it in a HttpHandler (as either an ashx file, or as a handler referenced in your web.config). The AJAX client isn't able to access your class direct from the assembly!

Comment: ah, an ashx file might just work.  i'm working with some very wacky limitations here but an ashx file should be ok

Comment: The ashx was accepted by the architect here and it works fine.  Thanks for all the help ppl